# Question about identity functions as defined by Huffman and Kunze in Linear Algebra appendix

Tags: functions

Here is the statement:

One question of interest is the following. Suppose f is a function from X into Y. When is there a function g from Y into X such that g(f(x)) = x for each x in X?

Roughly speaking, we want a function g which ‘sends each element of Y back where it came from.’ In order for such a g to exist, f clearly must be into, that is, f must have the property that if $x_1$ does not equal $x_2$ then $f(x_l)$ does not equal  $f(x_2)$. If f is one-to-one, such a g does exist.

It is defined as follows: Let y be an element of Y. If y is in the range of f, then there is an element x in X such that y = f(x); and since f is l:l, there is exactly one such x. Define g(y) = x. $\textbf{If y is not in the range of f, define g(y) to be any element of X. Clearly we then have g o f = I.}$

Could someone provide me with an example of the bolded portion of the text?

Comment: Do you think there could be an element $x \in X$ such that $g(f(x)) \neq x$?

Answer (score 0):

f(x) in g(f(x)) is in f(X). f never maps a point in X to a point in Y\f(X). So, the definition of g on Y\f(X) is irrelevant. For example, you can define g(Y\f(X)) = {x0} (x0 in X).

Comment: f(x) in g(f(x)) is in f(X) makes sense to me as an element of the range  of f will always be in the set of the range of f. f never mapping a point in X to a point in Y\f(X) does not make sense to me. This is the case for when y isn't in the range of f right? Wouldn't this make f a function in which f(X) = Y thus it would make sense that if y isn't in the range of f and it also never maps a point in X to a point in Y, the function would have to be onto wouldn't it? I thought f was an into function, not an onto function.